# Simple Linked List (FILO) not working

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Here is my Code. A Simple FILO Linked List but the error i'm getting is weird. its on the Insert Function where i declare temp, saying Node is undeclared. Don't understand how Ive done this like 10 times and no errors. Thank you for your time.

//Linked List: Inserting a node at the beginning (FILO)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head; //Global


void Insert (int x)
{
    struct Node* temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void Print()
{
    struct Node* temp = head;  //We use a temporary because we dont want to lose the reference to the head
    printf ("List is: ");

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf (" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    printf ("\n");
}


int main(){

    head = NULL; //empty list
    int n,i,x;

    printf ("How many numbers?\n");
    scanf ("%d",&n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter the Number\n");
        scanf ("%d",&x);
        Insert(x);
        Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: `(Node*)` delete this or change to `(struct Node*)`

Comment: General warning:[do not cast malloc return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Besides the fact that casting `malloc()` & Friends is not needed in C (nor recommended) `Node` is not defined, as C is not C++. The code just defines `struct Node`, so use `struct Node`.

Comment: Your program won't compile as *Node* (without struct) is undefined.

Comment: You misspelt `struct Node` when casting the return value from `malloc()`.  The good news is that you needn't (and shouldn't) cast `void *` like that.  Instead, simply write `struct Node* temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`

Answer (score 4):

[DO NOT CAST MALLOC RETURN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

The solution of your problem is simply to avoid casting malloc return or use the correct type: `struct node*`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* head; //Global


void Insert (int x)
{
    struct Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void Print()
{
    struct Node* temp = head;  //We use a temporary because we dont want to lose the reference to the head
    printf ("List is: ");

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf (" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    printf ("\n");
}


int main(){

    head = NULL; //empty list
    int n,i,x;

    printf ("How many numbers?\n");
    scanf ("%d",&n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter the Number\n");
        scanf ("%d",&x);
        Insert(x);
        Print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```